# Kubuntu 18.04 switch users

Tags: kubuntu

I know in Ubuntu 14.04 Unity I could log onto my account and keep another account's session active by clicking on the gear in the top right and selecting my name.  How is this done in Kubuntu 18.04?  I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [user switch widget](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=133825) to your desktop if you have installed plasma-widgets-addons.

Comment: "Click on the top right corner" works in Unity, not KDE. The "user switch widget" is horrible. It allows me to switch to a user that is already logged on or to select an empty space to log on as someone who is not currently logged on. Once I go down this path, I can't log into my current session, so I end up with two sessions running as the same user. I can log off of one session but then I can't get back into the other one, so I can never log off. Reboot required.

Answer (score 0):

To switch users, click on the application launcher (or press the super key) and click on Leave.  Switch User is one of the options.  This option was omitted from both the Leave menu available from the top-right of the desktop and from the Leave menu when right-clicking on the desktop.

As K7AAY states, this functionality is also available through the User Switch widget.  It looks like the widget exposes the same bad behavior that is in the underlying system, so don't blame the widget.

The feature meets the need to switch from one account to another active account's session, or to log on to an account that does not currently have an active session -- kind of.  One attempt produced a command-line-only interface, like hitting ALT-F2 in Unity.  Another attempt logged me in and produced a desktop environment, but when I logged out, I didn't get a regular login screen -- graphics and buttons were messed up -- and I couldn't tell what account I was logging in to.  As Kubuntu is my only experience with Ubuntu 18.04 beyond a 5-minute teaser for 4 desktop environments, I don't know if the problem lies in KDE or in Ubuntu.

In my case, my immediate need was to install software for a non-privileged user without having them log out and lose work.  I suppose the correct solution is to bypass the GUI nonsense altogether, open a terminal, and do:

```
su {AdminUser}
{password}
sudo apt-get install {application}
exit
exit
```

...which is what I did.  I guess I expected Ubuntu 18.04 would be as easy to use as Ubuntu 14.04.  I suspect my difficulty was caused by switching from Unity to KDE.